# Creating Java Boilerplate Code with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, boilerplate

Is it possible to create a template/live template with IntelliJ to create the full stack of usual boilerplate for a Domain Object?

Let me give you an example: A usual structure in in a backend could look something like this:

1. Define a functional domain object: Foobar
2. Create the entity FoobarEntity:

   ```
   @Entity @Table(name="foobar") @Getter @Setter 
   public class FoobarEntity implements Persistable<Long> {
       @Id
       private Long id;
       @Column
       private String someData;
       @Column
       private String someMoreData;
   }
   ```
3. Now the boilerplate party starts, create data transfer objects, data access objects, services, ...: Create `FoobarDto` (to get started), `Interface FoobarDao` (CRUD) and default implementation `FoobarDaoJpa`, `Interface FoobarService` (CRUD) and default implementation `FoobarServiceImpl`, a mapper to map from Entity to Dto `FoobarDtoMapper`, maybe a Spring config `FoobarConfig`, maybe a filter object to search `FoobarSearchFilter`, maybe some more Classes for a REST api like `FoobarRessource`, `FoobarController`, ...

Some further considerations: More annotations (like `@Service` or something like that) would be somehow useless since the all the classes start with the same code base (like `add`, `delete`, `edit`, `load` methods for a service and a dao) but, however, will grow in the further process of development.

Is this somehow possible with IntelliJ (or another tool you know)?

Comment: This may help you. It's for android studios, but surely available for your IDE also, cz both are IntelliJ's products.

https://medium.com/google-developers/writing-more-code-by-writing-less-code-with-android-studio-live-templates-244f648d17c7#.yl404avdt

Answer (score 1):

You can create entities like that with hibernate plugin. It creates entities according to your table structure. Just add hibernate framework  to your project (in linux, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, then type `hibernate` and select `add hibernate framework`), then you'll get a task window like that:

[image]

Now right click on your projects name (will be different in your case) and select `Generate Persistence Mapping` > `By Database Schema`.

Now a window will open and you can select the tables you want to create an entity for.

Note that you need to have set up your database in idea to make this work.

For your third point, use [file templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html). Again, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, but then type `file template` - create the templates once and just use them...